# Реализовать появление изображения на фоне пункта меню

Tags: html, css, background

Как можно реализовать появление картинки на фоне пункта меню?
 Как на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом пункты меню могут быть разной ширины , **нужно чтобы картинка растягивалась до нужной ширины (зависит от длины текста)**.

Мой html код:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Work</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Мой css код:

```
.menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}

.menu li {
    font-family: 'Mensch-Regular';
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:24px;
    margin-top:32px;
}

.menu a {
    margin:20px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде не сложно , в два псевдоэлемента

```css
* {
  margin: ;
  padding: ;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

li:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 20px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
}

li:hover:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: 20px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">premium access</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/geabdb?editors=1100 с изменением цвета ссылки

Comment: Опередили меня))

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю воспользоваться вам псевдоэлементами:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 32px;
  background-color: #ECE8D4;
}

.menu li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Mensch-Regular';
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.menu a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a::before,
.menu a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 34px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 34px solid transparent;
}

.menu a::before {
  left: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid #ECE8D4;
}

.menu a::after {
  right: 0;
  border-right: 10px solid #ECE8D4;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #FF7752;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu a:hover::before,
.menu a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю менять фон при наведении используя картинку для точной передачи дизайна

```
 <nav>
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #f5d98b;
  list-style: none;
  li {
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin:  0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    &:hover {
     background-image:url("путь к картинке");
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
}
```